# how i can build a CAl in python?

Tags: python

```
a=float(input('lotfan adade khod ra vared konid:'))
b=float(input('lotfan adade badi khod ra vared konid:'))
c=input('lotfan amale morde nazar khod ra vare dkonid:')
if c == +:
    d=a+b
    print("a"+"+"+"="+d )
elif c == -:
    d=a-b
    print("a" + "-" + "=" + d)
elif c== *:
    d =a*b
    print("a" + "*" + "=" + d)
elif c== /:
    d =a/b
    print("a" + "/" + "=" + d)
```

eroor=
  File "C:/Users/AVAJANG/PycharmProjects/start/test.py", line 4
    if c == +:
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: You need to quote your strings: `if c == "+":` etc.

Comment: You need to put those operators as string literals, e.g. `if c == '+'`. What's a CAI?